# iPhone Application crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

When I do the following my application crashes and I get an error (terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException') whenever i run the simulation:

```
for (...)
    [Array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Trip %i",i+1]]
```

OK after writing the problem I have found that the error is "0 is beyond bounds for empty array".

Comment: Can you post the full loop code and also a printout of the Exception being raised?

Comment: Post some more code showing the initialization of the class and how it's used and released.  What's the exception?  Chances are good that the object you're trying to replace doesn't exist like you think it does.

Comment: Replace your for with `for (int i=0; i<[Array1 count]; i++)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You really really really need to post the type of exception and your code to give us a reasonable chance of solving your problem**.  However, I'm going to taker a shot at it anyway.

My guess is your code looks something like this:

```
Array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: someNumber];

for (i = 0 ; i < someNumber ; ++i)
{
    [Array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Trip %i",i+1]];
}
```

All arrays start out with 0 objects in them even if you use `-initWithCapacity:`.  That method only provides a hint to the runtime that the array will grow to the specified size at some point.    You need to use `-addObject:`.

**Edit**

Yep, from your edit, I'm sure I am right.  The array has started out empty and you are trying to replace the object at index 0 which isn't there yet.

The code above should be changed as follows:

```
array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: someNumber]; // fixed naming convention too :-)

for (i = 0 ; i < someNumber ; ++i)
{
    [array1 addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Trip %i",i+1]];
}
```

`-addObject:` adds the new objects to the end of the array.

If you want something that looks more like a C or Java array, you can prefill the array with `NSNull` objects

```
array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 6]; // fixed naming convention too :-)

for (i = 0 ; i < 6 ; ++i)
{
    [array1 addObject: [NSNull null]];
}

// Now the following will work
[array1 replaceObjectAtIndex: 4 withObject: @"foo"];
```

Comment: yes you are right but can you plz tell where should i use the addObject ?? should it be when i initialize the array ?? just give an example on how to use coz i really don't have that much of knowledge with objective-c arrays

Comment: i actually thought about for a while but didn't know how to fill it with any random objects

Comment: thank you, but one more thing plz show me an example of how i should do it and where ??

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `replaceObjectAtIndex` method with `NSArray` array type object, there is possibility of getting exception (crashed).

Use `NSMutableArray` for  managing a modifiable array of objects.

Although `replaceObjectAtIndex` can also be raised  the following Exception for **Object** and **Index**

**Index**: Raises an `NSRangeException` if index is beyond the end of the array.

**Object:** Raises an `NSInvalidArgumentException` if Object you are passing is nil.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is a guess (I can't do better without more information):

You cannot change an object you are iterating over.

(Bad) Example:

```
for (NSObject *obj in Array1){
    [Array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Trip %i",i+1]]
}
```